# Editing decompiled .jar files using Eclipse

Tags: java, class, jar, sms

I have a web application, precisely Cyclos SMS mobile banking software that I need to edit some of the .jar files. I imported it as a .war file into Eclipse, edited the .java file that I wanted to, run clean; when I try to check the .jar file that needed to be updated with this change with jd-gui, I see that nothing has changed in it.

So I decided to edit the .jar file by decompiling it with jd-gui, and saving it to it source file; edited the .java file I wanted to edit by importing it into Eclipse; exported it as a .war file and substituted .jar for .war.

I decided to view the changes made, but in the file I edited, I saw that it tried to call other classes in other .jar files of the whole Cyclos SMS web app but could not see them, so it only compiled with errors. How do I edit the whole Cyclos SMS web app, since it has many .jar files, and just working on one of them at a time and recompiling it alone without compiling the entire web app will always lead to errors.

To simply put the question again, how to I edit .jar files in a big web app?

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the Cyclos download page http://www.cyclos.org/download, looks like sources are available.  Try downloading the source code and modifying it

Comment: Thanks. I have downloaded the source code, imported it into eclipse. The recompilation is the problem, when I edited from the .java files; save it and recompile it, it does not take effect in the .jar file that it ought to. I know very well that I am only not getting the right way to go about effecting the changes because I am a newbie to eclipse. Please, if you have practical guides to share in this, explain it step by step; take me as a toddler just learning his mother tongue. Possibly, if you can help out, the file is in this directory: cycl3-sms_1.2.2\sms\WEB-INF\lib\driver-gateway_1.2.jar

Comment: cyclo3-sms_1.2.2\gateway\WEB-INF\lib\driver-gateway_1.2.jar\HttpGatewayReceiverServlet.class. In this .class which is decompiled to it .java variant the the single thing I want to do is on line 105 (if using Notepad++) where : internationalNumber.toString().replace("+", "00"), to, message); I want to change it to internationalNumber.toString().replace("+", "009"), to, message); That's all. Kindly help please!

Comment: I've never worked with this lib before, nor looked through the code...
Can't you extend the HttpGatewayReceiverS‌​ervlet and override that method (even if the method contents is a copy of the parent), change that line in code then tell your app to use the implementation of that class instead